# How can I define custom Vagrant commands for a host machine?

Tags: vagrant

### The Situation

I'm creating a Vagrant development environment and would like to make it simple to run a command within the guest machine without having to run `vagrant ssh` or type the full command that is being run.

For example, I might have created a shell script in the guest machine which I would like to be able to trigger from the host machine using a well named command (e.g. `vagrant runMigrations`)

### The Research

I see that Vagrant has the concept of [aliases](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/aliases), but it isn't clear if these are defined on the host or guest.

My hope is I could write something like:

```
migrate=!vagrant ssh -c "~/migrationScript.sh"
```

And then, from the host, be able to simply type `vagrant migrate` in my project directory (and ONLY from my project directory -- this command would be project specific).

### The Question

Is it possible to define a vagrant command / alias which:

1. Is run on the host machine, and
2. only exists for a single project?

Comment: For your specific example, a trigger+provisioner would be the most direct course of action since you want something executed on the guest (provisioner) from a command executed on the host (trigger).

Comment: Thank you @MattSchuchard -- FWIW I would consider that a legitimate answer to this question if you're up for adding one (ideally with an example of what this would look like)

Comment: The caveat to both of those is that 1. the provisioner would additionally execute during initial machine creation 2. the trigger hooks in to the symbols for existing commands. I think both of these may conflict with your use case.